# implement custom executeUpdate from org.hibernate.query.Query class

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm using org.hibernate.query.Query class to perform updates over database entities, by calling the executeUpdate method:

```
public void updateMyClass (String value) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query<Void> query = session
            .createQuery("UPDATE MyClass SET value = :value ")
            .setParameter("value", value);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

I would like to prevent a direct call to executeUpdate(), since before and after each update, I perform some further logic. I need both the Session and Query classes to be accessible in the context, but to prevent direct usage in the executeUpdate().
I was thinking about extending both classes, but I couldn't find a way to extend the Session class, and also in that case I lose my IDE's HQL/SQL inspections and validations.

Is there a more straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't extend these interfaces. The best thing you could do is to create some kind of checkstyle rule that prevents the usage of this method, leading to a build error.